# Wrong result in MySql with ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query for search the newest progress.

This query show result with Ascending

```
Select VIDLEGENDA
FROM T_mst_activity inner join T_dtl_activity on t_mst_activity.vidactivity = t_dtl_activity.vidactivity WHERE vKodeProject = 'C002-1' 
order BY dtimeactivity asc, vworkhour asc
```

[image]

The last 3 is A.01, A.02, B.01

I want pick the last Result, so i use Descending like this image

```
Select VIDLEGENDA
FROM T_mst_activity inner join T_dtl_activity on t_mst_activity.vidactivity = t_dtl_activity.vidactivity WHERE vKodeProject = 'C002-1' 
order BY dtimeactivity desc, vworkhour desc
```

[image]

But the 3 Result in the top is B.01, A.01, A.02.

But the result should be B.01, A.02, A.01.

if there is something wrong with my query?

This is my Structure table :

T_mst_Activity 
[image]

T_dtl_Activity
[image]

FOR Ronald :
this select vidlegenda, dtimeactivity and vworkhour with ASC
[image]

this select vidlegenda, dtimeactivity and vworkhour with DESC
[image]

Comment: Well not much sure but why not just `order by VIDLEGENDA desc`? instead of `order BY dtimeactivity desc, vworkhour desc`

Comment: @Rahul i think so.. it maybe false because `order by dTimeactivity` and by `vworkhour`

Comment: i not use order by vidlegenda because i must have the realtime progress. so i must use dtimeactivity and vworkhour

Comment: @Ronald i have put the table T_mst_Activity and T_dtl_Activity.

Comment: just try your query but replace `Select VIDLEGENDA` with `Select VIDLEGENDA,dtimeactivity,vworkhour` you can see clearly how its order by

Comment: i have done put the result, please check my post ronald

Answer (score 0):

you can see when you **desc** it **row 2 and 3** have **same dtimeactivity and same vworkhour** isn't it? because of **vidlegenda not in order so the default order is asc when the condition meet same dtimeactivity and same vworkhour**.. so you must give 3 order by.. first **dtimeactivity** then **vworkhour** and  last **vidlegenda** to **desc** it

try this :

```
Select VIDLEGENDA
FROM T_mst_activity inner join T_dtl_activity on t_mst_activity.vidactivity = t_dtl_activity.vidactivity WHERE vKodeProject = 'C002-1' 
order BY dtimeactivity desc, vworkhour desc, VIDLEGENDA desc
```

Comment: oke ronald, thanks for your answer.
The result work fine, but the result is just sort the vidlegenda, not the realtime vidlegenda.
If i enter the A.02 first and A.01 Second, its take the A.02 the realtime, but it should be A.01. So i cant use order by vidlegenda for avoid the vidlegenda sort by the number.

Comment: what about order by your enter date and time? if you want to realtime output

Comment: I just enter the date and the MySql display the vidlegenda in the last time entered, if i use asc the last result is the realtime, but its just wrong with desc.

How can i get just the last without use desc and limit 1 or limit 3?